# Оптимизация подзапросов SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Имееться вот такой запрос

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS item.* ,     
    (SELECT metro  FROM catalog_metro as metro WHERE metro.id = item.metro LIMIT 1) as metroname ,
    (SELECT alias FROM catalog_metro as metro WHERE metro.id = item.metro LIMIT 1) as m_alias,
    (SELECT rajon_id FROM catalog_metro as metro WHERE metro.id = item.metro LIMIT 1) as rajon_id,
    (SELECT rajon FROM catalog_rajoni as rajon WHERE rajon_id = rajon.id LIMIT 1) as rajon,
    (SELECT alias FROM catalog_rajoni as rajon WHERE rajon_id = rajon.id LIMIT 1) as r_alias,

    (SELECT option FROM catalog_option as option WHERE item.option = option.id LIMIT 1) as option,
    (SELECT alias FROM catalog_option as option WHERE item.option = option.id LIMIT 1) as n_alias,
    (SELECT color FROM catalog_color as color WHERE color.id = item.color LIMIT 1) as color,
    (SELECT alias FROM catalog_color as color WHERE color.id = item.color LIMIT 1) as coloralias,

    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(service) as srv FROM catalog_gs as gs where gs.item=item.id GROUP BY gs.item) as gs
    FROM catalog_item as item WHERE 1 ORDER by item.order ASC
```

Вопрос в том как несколько очень похожих по своей сути подзапроса свести в один, и стоит ли это делать (исходя из производительности)

З.Ы. таблица большая около 600к строк , само собой это не все условия в where, просто упрощение для того что бы меньше писать, все равно они тут не существенны

По Вопросам в комментариях:
да вы правы лимит тут не нужен там сравнение 1 к 1 кроме момента с GROUP_CONCAT там многое к 1 
пробовал переписать все это join'ами но это привило к увеличению времени запроса, За подсказку с PRIMARY KEY уже спасибо

По структурам таблица item это список с кучей параметров (id значений из других таблиц в которых соответственно у свойств есть свои атрибуты) та таблица что service там просто список item.id и service.id из еще одной таблицы не участвующей в данном запросе

Comment: джойн-то вас по какой причине не устраивает?

Comment: можно структуру таблиц увидеть и  узнать что нужно в результате получить? потому что не понятно сразу что здесь написано. Что это "metro as metro"?

Comment: а limit в подзапросах актуальны, в metro может быть более одной записи с конкретным id ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  MIN(items_tabl.name_field), 
  MIN(metro.metro) as metroname, 
  MIN(metro.alias) as m_alias, 
  MIN(metro.rajon_id),  
FROM items_tabl
JOIN  metro ON metro.id = items_tabl.metro
GROUP BY items_tabl.FIELD_NAME_PRIMARY_KEY;
```

FIELD_NAME_PRIMARY_KEY - это название поля в таблице

Здесь групировка идет  по полю PRIMARY_KEY, оно имеет индекс, за счет этого запрос будет работать значительно быстрее.

Про форматирования кода нужно помнить :) а то читать его почти нереально. Везде писать as так же не стоит, иногда без него код легче читать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73531/discussion-on-answer-by-mykola-veriga---sql).